# Is my question "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked a question about how to recognize counterfeit Pis: [Recognizing a counterfeit Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93989/recognizing-a-counterfeit-pi)

It's getting close votes as "primarily opinion-based".

I don't see how asking for clear, definite indicators of low quality is mere "opinion". Am I in the wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I don't think it is opinion based, but I am just some guy, as btw is the guy who close-voted your question. If more users agree with that user I will take the workings of the Stackexchange community moderation for granted though.

I think it is a reasonable and answerable question. Though I reject the claim that one can somehow prove the non-existence of a fake Pi as the answer and the linked thread suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The question was NOT about any of the items in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

You asked 3 questions, the first 2 unanswerable (as there are no known counterfeits) so any answer to these would be speculation.

The 3rd "Is there anything I should keep in mind while buying one in-person from a local retailer?" is opinion-based or a shopping question - both off-topic.